# Sum up a vector

Tags: r

Here's my attempt with a `for` loop

```
for(j in seq(from=1, to=5, by=1)){
p2 <- sum(j, na.rm = FALSE)
print(p2)
}
```

I'm getting this as output:

```
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
```

but I need the sum of these variables, this equals `15`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slightly more abstract answer is (in case `p2`  in the problem statement is just representative of some value being calculated in a for loop):

```
runningTotal <- 0
for(j in seq(from=1, to=5, by=1)){
    p2 <- j # a trivial example of a value in a for loop
    runningTotal <- runningTotal + p2
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't do it this way.  The R way is

```
# Assumption:
j <- c(1,2,3,4,5)   # or j <- 1:5 
p2 <- sum(j)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest summing over a range to achieve the desired result:

```
R> for(j in seq(from=1, to=5, by=1)){ 
+   p2 <- sum(1:j, na.rm = FALSE) 
+   print(p2)
+ }
[1] 1
[1] 3
[1] 6
[1] 10
[1] 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't really understand "but I need the sum of these variables". Are you looking for `cumsum(1:5)` ?

```
> cumsum(1:5)
[1]  1  3  6 10 15
```